# City center or city's center?

Tags: idiomatic-language, possessives

> I own an apartment just outside the city center/city's center.

Can I say both? Which one would native speakers usually go with?

Answer (score 1):

*city center* is more idiomatic, though the other option isn't wrong (at least not from a grammar perspective). One way to see this is through the [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=city+center%2Ccity%27s+center&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3), which shows *city center* is used about 10 times as often as *city's center*:

[image]

Comment: Although the question uses the spelling 'center', I would add that 'city centre' has a similar preference of usage over 'city's centre'.

Comment: Heh, true. British English speakers would indeed go for *city centre*.

Answer (score 0):

Like most people, I would nearly always say "city centre" (and similarly "town centre").

If someone said "city's centre", I would interpret that slightly differently.  I might regard that as a reference to the geographical centre of the city, whereas the area generally known as the "city centre" might not be precisely in the middle.

If you drill down to the specific uses of "city's centre" in Google NGrams, there are various shades of meaning being conveyed that are often a bit different from what we normally mean when we say "city centre":

> The city takes up nearly 3,500 square miles of land, with 200 of these being occupied by the Wellspring, the deep, effervescent lake in the city's center.

The term "city centre" suggests a busy urban area.  It might sound odd to refer to a "lake in the city centre".

> In light of these spatial changes, the traditional geographical concept of a city's center and periphery is now of only limited use

You could probably also say "a city centre and a city periphery", but "city's centre and periphery" works better.

> At the city's center next to State House and the American Embassy is the Cotton Tree

The term "centre" is being used to refer to a specific point rather than a general area.

There are some sentences where "city centre" and "city's centre" work equally well, but others where they don't.

Comment: city center and a city's outskirts. periphery sounds like urban studies.

Comment: These were actual quotes (not ones I made up) - I probably should have included the sources.  It's likely that that quote is indeed from a book or article on urban studies.